# Is it possible to move variables above those upon which they depend?

Tags: bash, variables

I want to keep the configuration variables at the very top, but they depend upon other variables which need to be above them. How can I (if that's possible) move a *don't touch* section below a *config* section?

To illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash

#== don't touch ==
 dirpath=$(dirname "$1")
 dirname=$(basename $(dirname "$1"))

#== config ==
 path="$dirpath"   #using the value of $dirpath straight in config would be ugly.
 name="$dirname" 

 echo "$path" + "$name"
```

..but I want to move the *config* above everything else:

```
#!/bin/bash

#== config ==
 path="$dirpath"   #using the value of $dirpath straight in config would be ugly.
 name="$dirname" 

#== don't touch ==  
 dirpath=$(dirname "$1")
 dirname=$(basename $(dirname "$1"))

 echo "$path" + "$name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

The usual pattern is:

```
#!/bin/bash
function main()
{ 
    prepare
    do_step1 args ...
    do_step2 args ...
    do_step3 args ...
    do_step4 args ...

    exit 0
}

function prepare() { .... }
function do_step1() { ....}
function do_step2() { ....}
function do_step3() { ....}
function do_step4() { ....}

// entry point
main
```

As long as the (sub)function definitions precede invocation, they will be found nicely.

---

Literal answers:

No, you'd need to have functions for that, or you eval:

```
export dynamic="interesting"
function getsomething() { echo -n "$dynamic"; }

export dynamic="stuff"
echo "$(getsomething)"
```

will display "stuff", not "interesting"

---

The eval approach:

```
export param=value1
export dependent='$param' # (note the SINGLE quotes)

export param=value2
eval "echo $dependent"
```

will print, "value2", not "value1"

#### Cosmetics:

If it's just about don't touch source an include file:

```
  source donot_touch.sh
```

Comment: I think you're spot on, but I'm confused with the variable names. How would it look like with the ones I wrote? Would the configuration happen beside one of the `export asdf` lines?

Comment: I suggest you just move the lines (dirpath, dirname) into an include file, source that; they will be out of sight. Source it in the same place where you now define them

Comment: I like that for larger scripts, but since mine is 30 lines, it'd be overkill to have two files.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer to suit the question you seem now to be asking. _(To an extent I suggest you just live with it: Shell scripting is for pragmatics, philosophers or poets)_